# Background-image in Vaadin 14 Application does not load

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

I am currently developing a Vaadin 14 Webapp using Spring boot. 
I want to add a background-image to the app using css but the browser always says that it was unable to load the image.

VaddinView:

```
@Route("")
@CssImport("./styles/styles.css")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
...
```

styles.css

```
html{
    background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
}
```

Since I am using Spring boot my project structur looks like this:

```
project
 -src
   -main
     -java
       -...
          -MainView.java
     -resources
   -test
 -frontend
   -styles
     -styles.css
   -images
     -background.jpeg
```

When I replace the image URI with the URL of a web-image or use a gradient as a background-image everything works fine.

Comment: 1. what happens on `background-image: url("images/background.jpg");` or `background-image: url("frontend/images/background.jpg");` ? 2. Why is src/main/webapp or src/main/resources not being used in favor of  `frontend` folder?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the images should be placed in src/main/resources/static.

Comment: Workes when I run the Application with spring-boot in dev-mode. But when I deploy the war on a tomcat the image still will not load.

Comment: Can you inspect the content of the WAR file to be sure that it contains the image inside?

Comment: Yes it is in the WAR-File. Under /WEB-INF/classes/static/images/ .